# Display a pending icon when status is pending and Display a completed icon when status is completed

Tags: ajax, ember.js, get

[The General Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcq7x.png)

I want to be able to display a pending status icon in the area when the get request is still pending and the status of that request is pending, however I want it to display a completed status icon when the get request returns a status of completed.

In my handlebars:

```
{{!-- Status --}}
  {{#each search.data as |status|}}
    {{#if statusPending}}
      <p><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></i></span>&nbsp;</p>
    {{else}}
      <p><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>&nbsp;</p>
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
```

statusPending being an action that will check the status.

I was thinking something like:

```
actions: {
    statusPending: function() {
        if ('status' == 'pending') {
            Ember.$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: https://linktothing.com/slash/,
                    return: true,
            })
        }
    }
}
```

where status is in the header of the get request and pending is what it returns.

That is what I've got so far... but It doesn't work (of course). 
Any suggestion, code or links to relevant reading material is welcomed. By returning true it satisfies the if/else statement in the handlebars and therefore will show false - completed if not true.

***UPDATE***

Answer that worked for my case.

```
didInsertElement: function() {
      var _thing = this.get('thing');

      this.set('isPending', _thing.status === 'PENDING');
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should look like this:

```
{
    isPending: false

  checkStatus: function() {
    Ember.run.later(this, function() {
        Ember.$.ajax(/* your code here */).then(function(response) {
        if (response.status == 'finished status') {
            this.set('isPending', false);
        } else {
            this.checkStatus();
        }
      }.bind(this))
    }, 5000); //check every 5 seconds
  }

    actions: {
    startAsyncOperation: function() {
        this.set('isPending', true);
      this.checkStatus();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Not quite sure where that fits in the code.... can you provide a more complete answer please. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have the context of your application so I cannot say for sure. Anyway, this code should be placed in your component/controller, the same place where you put your actions.
startAsyncOperation is whatever action that starts the operation on the server, like user clicks a button and then sees the pending icon.